Why is the first node in the AQS queue empty
Why does AQS not directly use one of the competing threads as the head node when creating a synchronization queue, but instead creates an empty object as the head node.Why did the author do this
enter image description here this is the codeenter image description here

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Please don't use unexplained non-standard acronyms. I assume you're talking about AbstractQueuedSynchronizer but you should mention its full name in your question. Also, put Github links to the code you're referring to, as well as entering the code directly in your question as text.

The Java source for the AbstractQueuedSynchronizer explains it in the class comment:

The wait queue is a variant of a "CLH" (Craig, Landin, and Hagersten) lock queue.
[...]
CLH queues need a dummy header node to get started. But we don't create them on construction, because it would be wasted effort if there is never contention. Instead, the node is constructed and head and tail pointers are set upon first contention.

